# Rails has_many assosiations into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

Say you have `countries` which `has_may` `states`. I want to be able to pull them out if the db into a array that looks like this `[['America', ['Hawaii','Texas']], ['Australia', ['Queensland','Victoria','New South Whales']]]`. Obviously with the country being the first value and then the next value has nested inside it the `has_many` associations

I'm not sure how to get them looking like this. `pluck` can get just states or just countries but I don't think it can get both and sort them into an array like this.

I'm sure its simple but cant figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct way:

```
x = Countries.includes(:states).all
```

The code to convert to arrays (if you absolutely need it) would look like:

```
a = []
x.each do |item|
    y = [ item.name, [] ]
    item.states.each do |state|
        y[1] << state.name
    end
    a << y
end
```

Substitute the appropriate column names for `.name` to get the name from the Countries and States objects.

Comment: How can I see this as an actual array to know it is working right. currently it just shows `#<Countries::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f9df4e5cc68>`

Comment: It's not an actual array, although it'll act exactly like the structure you described. If you need to convert it to an array of strings you can iterate through it, then through each item's `.states` attribute, building your arrays as you go. But for most purposes you probably won't need to convert it, and depending on what you actually want to do you may even be better off doing direct queries to get the specific items you need as you need them.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Your getting closer. What does the `a` variable do, it just stays empty? The `y` variable seems to be overwritten each loop so it only outputs the values it was assigned on the last loop.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the last line of the outer loop. And as I said, you probably won't need this code because you can do exactly this using `x` directly, and since arrays don't allow lookup by name there's no easy way to do usable access by index (the one thing you wouldn't be able to do with `x`).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more practical to have a structure like this:

```
{
  'America' => ['Hawaii','Texas'],
  'Australia' => ['Queensland','Victoria','New South Whales']
}
```

To get this, you could do something like:

```
{}.tap{ |h| countries.each{ |country| h[country.name] = country.states.map(&:name } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it with something like:

```
State.select('states.*, countries.name as country_name').joins(:country).group_by(&:country_name)
```